# Trouble getting robots.txt to show up the site description correctly

Tags: asp.net, robots.txt

We have a site **www.demoxxxx.com** , If the user types in that url he gets redirected to **www.demo1xxx.com**
from where since he is not authenticated he gets redirected to the STS , **www.sts.com** for authentication.

We have put the **robots.tx**t file in the root of **www.sts.com**, What i'm expecting is a description to be shown when the user searches for demoxxxx. At the moment the description just reads .

**"Robots.txt is too restrictive"**. Any pointers here would be really helpful.

Comment: @SherinMathew no luck till now..